# PHP OOP, Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setAuthor() on string

Tags: php, fatal-error

I use PHP version 7 and i get always this error, when i creat a news article:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setAuthor() on string in D:\xampp\htdocs\entwicklung\tools\adminlogin\lib\mod\news\newsForm.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\entwicklung\tools\adminlogin\lib\mod\news\newsForm.php on line 14

Here i creat my object and would save the article in my database:

```
if(isset($_POST["publish"]))
{
    $news = new News();
    $title = $news->setTitle($db, $_POST["ueberschrift"]);
    $news =  $news->setNews($db, $_POST["artikel"]);
    $author = $news->setAuthor($db, $_POST["autor"]); //This is line 14

    News::newsArticleCreate($db, $title, $news, $author);

}
```

This is my setter-method for the author:

```
    function setAuthor($db, $author)
    {
        if(!empty($author))
        {
            $author = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $author);
            return $this->author = trim($author);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: what setNews returns ?

Comment: I think it need to be:-

`$news->title = setTitle($db, $_POST["ueberschrift"]);
$news->news =  setNews($db, $_POST["artikel"]);
$news->author = setAuthor($db, $_POST["autor"]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setAuthor() on
>   string

The error says that you are trying to call setAuthor on a string ( $news ) rather than on an object of News Class. 
If you replace the following line:

```
$news =  $news->setNews($db, $_POST["artikel"]);
```

with

```
$news->setNews($db, $_POST["artikel"]);
```

It should work fine.